# Is there a way to auto summarize bulk data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, summary, summarize

I am want to be able to take "bulk" material lists and have them automatically summarized to "sum" like-with-like items.

For example, would there be an efficient way to accomplish the following?

Is there an efficient way to get from: [image: Screenshot 1] to. . . [image: Screenshot 2]?

Your help will make my life a LOT easier!  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you looked at sumifs() and index() with match() ?

Comment: You should be able to do something like what you show easily with Power Query. But, if the particular coloring is important, you'll need to either do that manually, or also write a VBA script to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a pivot table. Put the relevant Columns up in columns and the Sum of `PCS` and `ORDER` in the data area. Play with the formatting / layout. You can refresh the data after adding new lines.

Comment: Is it possible to do what you're talking about and end up with the exact same formatting as what I have pictured?

Comment: Wolfgang Jacques - can you please help me out with how to accomplish this to give me the exact same format as depicted?  That would help me out a lot

Comment: @Bryan sorry, that would be tricky indeed and I cannot help at this point. If you cannot bend the pivot table in the wanted direction you could try to make a copy of your original sheet and put formulas in to pull the data from the pivot table. Or you try to use VBA to run through the original lines instead.